# C# winforms EasyTabs black line between border and content in win7

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a chrome-like browser in C#, but when I use EasyTabs to create Tabs like Chrome a black line comes between the window border and inside content.
How can I solve this?

[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance ♥

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the code in the program.cs at the particular object instance. It must be something to do with attributes/properties of the EasyTabs.
Share the codes here for further examination.

Comment: please see the codes here https://github.com/devlinuxuser/browser